# Ubuntu shortcuts interfering with my PHP Storm shortcuts

Tags: php, phpstorm

I am using PHP Storm on Ubuntu 13.
When I hit the shortcut alt-f1 which is supposed to trigger PHP-Storm's (Navigation-show-in)
nothing happens because I suppose the shortcut is mapped to the Ubuntu Desktop.
So what can I do to get alt-f1 working in PHP Storm.

(I do not want to remap the command since I am mentally so used to it)

Comment: *"So what can I do to get alt-f1 working in PHP Storm"* -- remove such shortcut from Ubuntu ?

Comment: well I was hoping that it would be possible to leave ubuntus shortcuts intact. So that only PHPSTorm has input focus then use the shortcuts supplied  by PHP Storm

Comment: AFAIK Ubuntu shortcuts are global and should have priority over app (but I could be wrong here).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please follow [this feature request to provide Ubuntu friendly keymap](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-55796) that will not conflict with the default system shortcuts (which always have priority).